# Java/Hibernate JPA: InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS and IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, table-per-class

I'm using Hibernate JPA.

Suppose I have these classes:

```
AbstractPerson
|--> ConcreteEmployee
|--> ConcreteCustomer
```

Is there any way to make the concrete classes have independent IDs?

I'm using InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS.

Comment: In at least one of the concrete classes, I'd like to have autoincremental numbers, like a customer number, independent of the 'shared' ID.

This is for a university assignment, so opinions on why this could be a bad idea are welcome. :P

Comment: It is possible with the Mapped superclass inheritance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide:

> #### [2.2.4.1. Table per class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1191)
>
> This strategy has many drawbacks (esp.
>   with polymorphic queries and
>   associations) explained in the JPA
>   spec, the Hibernate reference
>   documentation, Hibernate in Action,
>   and many other places. Hibernate work
>   around most of them implementing this
>   strategy using `SQL UNION` queries. It
>   is commonly used for the top level of
>   an inheritance hierarchy:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> public class Flight implements Serializable { ... }
> ```
>
> This strategy supports one-to-many
>   associations provided that they are
>   bidirectional. **This strategy does
>   not support the `IDENTITY` generator
>   strategy: the id has to be shared
>   across several tables. Consequently,
>   when using this strategy, you should
>   not use `AUTO` nor `IDENTITY`**.

So I'm afraid what you want is not supported (and I suggest to use `GenerationType.TABLE`).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll have to generate the customer number myself then.