# JPA OneToMany using Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I have the following classes:

Hardware.java

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public class Hardware{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    private String serialnumber;    

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="hardware")
    private List<Equipment> equipments;
}
```

Computer.java

```
    @Entity
    public class Computer extends Hardware {

    private String hostname;
    private String macAdress;
    private String ipNumber;

    public Computer(){
        super();
    }

    public Computer(String serialnumber, String hostname,
        String macAdress, String ipNumber) {
        super(serialnumber);
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.macAdress = macAdress;
        this.ipNumber = ipNumber;
    }
}
```

NetworkDeivce.java

```
    @Entity
    public class NetworkDevice extends Hardware {

    private String hostname;
    private String ipAdress;

    public NetworkDevice(){
        super();
    }

    public NetworkDevice(String serialnumber, String hostname,
            String ipAdress) {
        super(serialnumber);
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
    }
}
```

And now the class that is mapped to the Hardware Class:

Equipment.java

```
@Entity
public class Equipment {

    public Equipment(){
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String serialnumber;
    private String info;

    @ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="HW_ID")
    private Hardware hardware;
}
```

Now if I add a Equipment to a Computer it all works finde, but if I try to add Equipment to a NetworkDevice I get this Error:
Internal Exception:

Internal Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventorytool_beta`.`EQUIPMENT`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EQUIPMENT_HW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HW_ID`) REFERENCES `COMPUTER` (`ID`))
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO EQUIPMENT (INFO, SERIALNUMBER, HW_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(domain.hardware.Equipment@600a620d)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at main.dbTest(main.java:74)
    at main.main(main.java:18)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventorytool_beta`.`EQUIPMENT`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EQUIPMENT_HW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HW_ID`) REFERENCES `COMPUTER` (`ID`))
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO EQUIPMENT (INFO, SERIALNUMBER, HW_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(domain.hardware.Equipment@600a620d)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:913)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventorytool_beta`.`EQUIPMENT`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EQUIPMENT_HW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HW_ID`) REFERENCES `COMPUTER` (`ID`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

So I think it's a problem with the inheritance... I'm not very good at JPA..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the schema that was generated. You should had three different tables for hardware, due to your inheritance strategy: one for `Hardware`, one for `Computer` and one fon `NetworkDevice`. The problem is that `HW_ID` can only reference one table. Here your JPA provider chose `Computer`, probably because it's first in alphabetical order, but it can't handle all three classes.

Consider using another inheritance strategy, like `JOIN`.

Comment: I changed the strategy to JOIN and now it works like intended.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code where you insert Equipment to a NetworkDevice. It looks like HW_ID does not exists in the master-table(Hardware). Because it is trying to insert nonexistent Master-Table HW_ID as foreign-Key in child table(Equipment).

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Yes it comes from your inheritance strategy. You can't use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` with `table_per_class`.

See [Java/Hibernate JPA: InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS and IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154649/java-hibernate-jpa-inheritancetype-table-per-class-and-ids)