# JPA Inheritance TABLE_PER_CLASS throws MappableContainerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, classcastexception

Something is wrong with the JPA Inheritance and the server throws an error. There are many questions already asked on the topic, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem, so here are the details on what I have so far...

The superclass:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PERSON_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TRIGGER_PERSON_PRIMARY_KEY")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TRIGGER_PERSON_PRIMARY_KEY", sequenceName = "PERSON_AI_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID", updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected int personId;
```

The subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICANT")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="APPLICANT_ID")
public class Applicant extends Person {
}
```

The error message:

```
The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
```

Comment: the discriminator is a bit pointless, since each class has its own table and hance any table is not shared.

Comment: @NeilStockton At this point it probably is, but what about when another class extends the Person class which is going to happen?

Comment: That class is then going to have its own table also. An inheritance (in JPA) strategy applies to ALL classes in the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to fix this. There have been several steps I've taken:

1. Another class extending Person was throwing an error, so I've fixed the dependency.
2. I've changed the inheritance type to JOINED, which is actually what I'm looking for - different tables for the different columns and one root table for the common stuff.
3. As a consequence of 2. there was no more necessity of keeping the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn also.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have `@Id` in both *super* class and *sub* class.

**Solution**

Remove `@Id` from sub class `Applicant`

For more:

1. [Spring 3.1 Hibernate 4 exception for Inheritance [cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087011/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-exception-for-inheritance-cannot-be-cast-to-org-hibernat)
2. [Java/Hibernate JPA: InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS and IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154649/java-hibernate-jpa-inheritancetype-table-per-class-and-ids)

Comment: I don't have the annotation @Id on the subclass, just a id field in the Table called APPLICANT_ID. Otherwise how is the connection between the tables going to be managed?

Comment: @Galya please check GenerationType.TABLE instead of GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Comment: I need the Id to be generated by the sequence, since my persistence works with Oracle DB.

Comment: Would you please add Person and Applicant class in details @Galya

Comment: There is absolutely nothing else related, only fields annotated with @Column - name, email, phone, etc... No other relations, joins or ids.